# Joomla 2.5 with Virtuemart

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, virtuemart

Is it possible to redirect the user to a different page when an item is added to the cart? for example i would like them to go the the enter details page and then from here i want them to view the cart.

If it is possible how would it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing the address on line 85 of controllers->cart.php to the location of the page i want to redirect to.